# npm install $module installs dependencies of module at depth 0

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to install a module that maintains its actual dependency folder structure, however:

e.g. `npm install some-module` inside `my-module`

installs all the dependencies of some-module, as well as the dependencies of the dependencies of some-module recursively, as depth 0 dependencies of the modules that it is installed in.

```
my-module/
    node_modules/
        dependency of some-module
        dependency of dependency of some-module
        dependency of some-module
        dependency of some-module
        some-module
        dependency of some-module
        dependency of dependency of dependency of some-module
        dependency of some-module
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a feature of npm 3.x, dependencies are installed in a hybrid flat structure. The first version is installed at depth 0, then any subsequent versions will be installed inside the module that requires them

Comment: @ndonohoe wow, that's interesting, do you know the reasoning behind this choice?  Also, I ended up downgrading to npm 2.15.9 for the time being.

Comment: I think mainly to reduce the size of the node_modules folder, with npm 2.x a dependency might exist in 100 different places especially if it is a common one like lodash, bluebird etc. Also reduces problems with file path length on Windows